# Google analytics, how _setDomainName works with iframes?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, cross-domain

on our site we would like to track with Google Analytics user actions in iframe content. The iframes are hosted on a different and 3rd level domain. For some reason my setup doesn't work.

Situation:
In the iframe I want to use two google trackers: one from the parent site, and a separate just for the iframe. I also want to use Events and VPVs. When browsed the page can be seen in GA account's "real-time overview" section. But I don't see a VPV which is attached to Submit button click.

I also don't really understand how function "_setDomainName" works and what should be there. These are separate issues and any help would be much appreciated.

The setup:
On parent site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'parent.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
  var iframe = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
  iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('http://mydomain.iframedomain.net/page.aspx');
});

</script>
```

ON Iframe page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['a._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
            _gaq.push(['a._setDomainName', 'parent.com']);
            _gaq.push(['a._setAllowLinker', true]);
            _gaq.push(['a._trackPageview']);

            /* this is second tracking account */
            _gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-2']);
            _gaq.push(['b._setDomainName', 'iframedomain.net']);
            _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);

            (function () {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

        </script>
```

Then on a button click event I call this function:

```
             function track() {
                 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/search-retailer-clicked']);
                 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search - Event', 'Click - Event', 'Search Retailer Button clicked']); 
             }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've named both trackers in the iframe (`a._setAccount` & `b._setAccount`), but in the button click event, you're using a default, unnamed tracker.

The outcome is that the virtual page view and event are getting sent to a tracker that hasn't had the account set. If you look at the tracking pixel requests (via `ga_debug.js`, `firebug`, `chrome developer tools`, or `fiddler`), they'll show a `UA-XXXXX-X` accountId.

You probably want something more like:

```
function track() {
  _gaq.push(['a._trackPageview', '/search-retailer-clicked']);
  _gaq.push(['a._trackEvent', 'Search - Event', 'Click - Event', 'Search Retailer Button clicked']); 
  _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview', '/search-retailer-clicked']);
  _gaq.push(['b._trackEvent', 'Search - Event', 'Click - Event', 'Search Retailer Button clicked']); 
}
```